# How to change ubiquity release name

Tags: ubiquity, release

I want to build a custom distribution,

How can I change the release name in ubiquity installer ? ( where it says "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu")

Comment: Have you tried this forum thread?  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8591740#post8591740

Comment: thats not the one. The installer picks up Ubuntu from ${RELEASE} which is what I am trying to replace. Unfortunately I am still struggling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look on the media itself - there is a folder called **.disk**.  In there is a file called **info**.  The release name is there and can be changed.

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663191) 
.
I would use ISO Master (search for this in Software Center) to alter your ISO.

[image]

At a guess, if you use ISO Master to change your master ubuntu.iso .disk/info file, then this should be carried across into your remastered custom distro.

If this doesnt work, then probably just best to use ISO Master post the build to change the release name.

Comment: yes, i know. but i am using an iso file which i am going to customize using UCK. How do i find the .disk folder in an iso?

Comment: ok - I think there is a confusion - you want to change the distro name - the release name is 'ubuntu 11.04 "Natty Narwahl" i386' etc.  I believe the values you need to change is the stuff in /etc/lsb-release - see the enclosed link.  I'll try to investigate further - but have a look at this https://answers.launchpad.net/uck/+question/118341

Comment: You know, I have tried changing the .disk/info file on a USB stick and it worked fine. But my question is, i am using UCK to customize ubuntu, where do I find that .disk/info folder in an iso? Or in other words, what file should i change so that the final product on will have a .disk/info with my custom name.

Comment: @ubuntuser You need to put all this information in your question, it's nonobvious that you're using UCK from the question as it is written currently.

Comment: @jorge: true i should have. @fossfreedom: dint know about the iso master thing. awesome! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to develop my own distribution from the currently installed distribution. So, there is no .disk folder in the installed system. 
So, how will I change that ?

Comment: if you want to do that, use remastersys. otherwise you have to build from scratch using programs like uck

Comment: Does UCK provides editing even the basics ?

Comment: yes,it does, it allows very high level changes but you need to have good knowledge of the cli.