# Where do I need to change "Ubuntu" when naming my own custom distribution?

Tags: custom-distributions

i am building my own distro (which i am almost done) but one thing left is the name of it. since i am not sure what to name it im leaving the "ubuntu" there

i know i will have to change the following files

- /etc/lsb-release
- /etc/issue

to my own name and version and code name. am i missing other files?

(on my site it shows it's an ubuntu version - i read the tm etc... but i want the name of my distro to be there)
thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's my two cents about this:

You can try to change the name of the distribution but be **careful**, if you change something wrong, you might encounter problems while installing or later when you will use it. But if your **absolutely** need to change it here's what you can try:

The two you provided are correct (you can also update /etc/issue.net just to be sure). The other thing you can do is this:

Open the ISO (ISO Master) file and go to the folder called .disk. In there is a file called info. The release name is there and can be changed. [view this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43942/how-to-change-ubiquity-release-name)

This should change the name of your distribution.

If that does not work, you can change the following files:

*NOTE: the location might change depending the version you are using and file might be not found as well*

- /boot/grub/grub.cfg
- /etc/grub.d/00_header
- /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
- /usr/share/yelp/ (all files & all sub folders)
- /var/run/motd
- /etc/motd
- /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
- /lib/init/rw/motd
- /etc/gdm/failsafeXinit
- /etc/samba/smb.conf
- /usr/share/gnome-about/gnome-version.xml
- /usr/share/pyshared/usbcreator/install.py
- /usr/bin/grub-mkrescue
- /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/config.h
- /usr/sbin/grub-install.real
- /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig
- /usr/sbin/grub-mknetdir
- /usr/sbin/grub-reboot
- /usr/sbin/grub-set-default

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to look at '/etc/os-release' too. (i am experimenting on 'ubuntu 16.04 LTS').
hope it helps someone. 
good day.