# How do I remove Ubuntu Branding from LiveCD?

Tags: custom-distributions, branding

I am making a distro based on Ubuntu, I'm using the LiveCDCustomization (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) and I need to remove any Ubuntu branding, which I believe is just logos and editing the lsb_release file. When looking for how to remove the branding, I cam across a post that's best answer was to go to this page on Ubuntu and follow from there: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

The problem is, there's nothing saying *how* to remove the branding, only that you have to.

EDIT: I'm sorry if this is a duplication. As far as I know, I don't see any posts about this.
May you please help me out? I'm planning on releasing it before or on the day of 19.04, thank you :)

EDIT 2: I'm really sorry if I wasted any of y'all's time, but It turns out what I was planning on making is a flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: To reviewers: This question is either too broad or possible duplicate of [How do I remove any Ubuntu brand and trademark from my Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1017305/37165); or [Where do I need to change “Ubuntu” when naming my own custom distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83521/37165) and related [Custom Distro Trademark usage](https://askubuntu.com/q/682140/37165).

Comment: "which I believe is just logos and editing the lsb_release file"  Nope. You will also need to recompile all the binaries from the source code.

Comment: Why would you do that? It is Ubuntu, all work done by that team and upstream from them and you just want to remove the brand name and pretend it is something else? Does not seem fair to me.

Comment: A real 'distro' includes package repos, support, and much more. Some folks call their minor tweak to the default package set a 'distro', but it's not -- it's a 'respin'. It's difficult to tell from your question which category yours falls into. If your new distro involves substantial changes (like a new DE) that are in demand, consider recruiting a few friends and becoming a new 'flavor' of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 I plan on using the deepin desktop seeing as there's no version of Ubuntu that uses it. I'll try and find some people to work this on to make it a flavour :)

Comment: Hmmm. You might want to talk to the deepin (distro) folks before you start an Ubuntu Flavor project for it. The Deepin folks are (justifiably) proud of their complete distro, and may not be interested in becoming an Ubuntu upstream contributor. Note also that others have trod this path before; installing Deepin is usually a mere matter of installing the correct PPA.

Comment: You may be right. I'll contact them right now. Thank you for the clarification by the way.

Comment: voted to close as duplicate, but +1 - this is important. See [Eliah Kagan's comments here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3877?m=43890143#43890143)